# Error using glm in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply simple binomial logistic regression in json data I downloaded from Kaggle:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/two-sigma-connect-rental-listing-inquiries/data

I changed values of interest_level column to either 1 if the value is "high" and 0 if otherwise. 
This is my first time using glm so any help is welcome.

```
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(nnet)

json.data <- fromJSON(file = "train.json")
json.data = as.data.frame(t(do.call(rbind, json.data)))
#head(json.data)
#colnames(json.data)
x <- json.data$interest_level
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (json.data$interest_level[i] =="high"){
    json.data$interest_level[i] <- 1
  }else {json.data$interest_level[i] <- 0}
}
indexes = sample(1:nrow(json.data), size=0.5*nrow(json.data))
train.data <- json.data[indexes,]
test.data <- json.data[-indexes,]
model <-    glm(train.data~interest_level,family=binomial(link='logit'),data=train.data)
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = train.data ~ interest_level, data =   train.data,  : invalid type (list) for variable 'train.data'
```

Comment: Is `train.data` a data frame or the name of a column?

Comment: The error message explains the issue: `invalid type (list)`. Your outcome variable must be a vector.

Comment: you are passing the full dataset `train.data` as the outcome (left hand side of `~`) which is not correct. Use the name of your outcome variable.